# Filebeat concatenate multiple files to one file

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have a shared folder in my server that contain some files. i read these file with filebeat(version 5.0) and send them to logstash for processing. when i run this process, the number of files that i received in logstash output are lower than the actual number of files in shared folder. 
I understand that if there isn't \r\n at the end of file, filebeat didn't recognize that file finish and concatenate next file to this file and send these two files as one event to logstash.

for example file 1 is send as one event
file 1:

```
> - 23L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-23R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
> - 41L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-41R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
> - 42L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-42R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
> - 43L/AKEXXXX/XXX/330/C2-43R/AKEXXXX/XXX/683/BF0\r\n
> - SI\r\n
> - ;\r\n
> - \r\n
```

but file 2 is not recognize as one file and it concatenate to next file that is ok

file 2:

```
- 23L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-23R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
- 41L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-41R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
- 42L/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X-42R/AKEXXXX/XXX/80/X\r\n
- 43L/AKEXXXX/XXX/330/C2-43R/AKEXXXX/XXX/683/BF0\r\n
- SI\r\n
- ;\r\n
```

i play with all filebeat configuration options, but it doesn't help. do you have an idea how can handle and resolved this problem?

Comment: "the number of files that i received in logstash output are lower. . ." - How are you measuring the number of files? Filebeat sends data line by line.

Comment: I used multi line in filebeat that send each file as a one line. so if i have 100 files, after processing i have 80 files which some of them consist of content of two or three files.

Comment: Can you update the question with more info. You didn't mention that you were using multline in Filebeat. What are the configs that you use for Filebeat and Logstash so someone could recreate the problem.